# Non-Specific Type in Expression.Lambda Generics

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, expression-trees

The following code works fine (it builds a generic OrderBy):

```
public class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var _List = new List<Item>
{
    new Item{ Name = "Smith", Value = 3},
    new Item{ Name = "Smith", Value = 2},
    new Item{ Name = "Wesson", Value = 1},
    new Item{ Name = "Wesson", Value = 4},
}.AsQueryable<Item>();

var _Type = typeof(Item);

// OrderBy
var _OrderByProperty = _Type.GetProperty("Value");
var _OrderByParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "x");
// OrderBy(x => x.Value)
var _OrderByBody = Expression.Property(_OrderByParameter, _OrderByProperty.Name);
var _OrderByLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, Int32>>
    (_OrderByBody, _OrderByParameter);
// apply the OrderBy
_List = _List.OrderBy(_OrderByLambda);
```

But, I woud like to change this line, in this way:

```
var _OrderByLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, object>>
    (_OrderByBody, _OrderByParameter);
```

Such a change would make the data type of the ordered column generic. However, such a change results in the following exception:

> Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

Any ideas?

**EDIT**, thank you for your answers, this works fine:

```
var _OrderByProperty = _Type.GetProperty("Value");
var _OrderByParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "x");
// OrderBy(x => x.Value)
var _OrderByBody = Expression.Property(_OrderByParameter, _OrderByProperty.Name);
var _OrderByConverted = Expression.Convert(_OrderByBody, typeof(object));
var _OrderByLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, object>>
    (_OrderByConverted, _OrderByParameter);
// apply the OrderBy
_List = _List.OrderBy(_OrderByLambda);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify that the return type of the body is exactly `System.Object`. You can do this by inserting a conversion (something C# does implicitly):

```
_OrderByBody = Expression.Convert(_OrderByBody, typeof(object));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Expression.Property(_OrderByParameter, _OrderByProperty.Name);` creates an expression that returns int. You will need to box it. So you'll need to wrap it in a Box expression. However if you want to make it generic you shall not box objects

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
_List = _List.OrderBy(_OrderByLambda);
```

This method expects the `Function<Item, int>` parameter (because `_Type.GetProperty("Value")` returns `Int32`), so you can't use `Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, object>>` type.

If you need the `object` generic function, then you have to change your class definition to this:

```
public class Item
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```